# Will my stabilized soldier die at the end of mission?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I stabilized a soldier, but I couldn't revive him. Will he die at the end of the mission?

Comment: What would be the point of stabilizing somebody if they died anyway?

Comment: You can heal them after.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to revive someone, you need a special skill from the Support tree.  Otherwise, you'll always just stabilize them.

Stabilized soldiers will live to fight another day, although they take a Will hit.  This makes them more likely to panic and succumb to Psi attacks in the future.

Comment: In higher difficulties you may want to dismiss soldiers with too low will as they may be a liability.

Answer (score 3):

No.
Like any wounded soldier he will need some time to recover(it takes much longer though)
But the thing about stabilized soldiers is they get a permanent -15 will.

Answer (score 1):

if you beat the mission, they will survive, but if you fail or abort, the stabilized units will die. just happened to me and i lost two high level supports.